# Are we allowed, by the definition of induction, to assume that $f_{1}(x)$ still has the same formula, even though we switched $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

I'm pretty sure i'm supposed to demonstate this by induction but i think there is a problem with the way the proposition is stated that impossibilitates that,  I need to prove that

For all natural number $n$, $f_{0}(x) = \frac{x}{x+1} \& f_{n+1}(x)=(f_{0}(f_{n}(x))) \implies f_{n}(x) = \frac{x}{(n+1)x + 1}$

So if we first verify it for n=0 then the explicit formula for $f_{n}$ is given. But then, if we try to verify it for any other $n$, let's say $n=1$, we would have the formula for $f_{0}(x)$ as always, and we would also have that $f_{2}(x) = f_{0}(f_{1}(x))$ but how is that suppose to lead us to conclude the explicit formula for $f_{1}$ if we don't know what $f_{2}(x)$ looks like?

Did I get induction wrong?

Comment: Note that $f_1(x) = f_0(f_0(x))$.

Comment: Yes but only when n = 0 right? How can that still hold if we consider other values of n?

Comment: Yes, but that's not a problem.  You can verify that $f_1(x) = \frac{x}{2x+1}$.  That's not the inductive proof, but the inductive step is not much different.

Comment: How can you verify that only with the given information on $f_{2}$ & $f_{0}$ ?

Comment: The induction step is like this: let $f_{n+1}(x) = f_0(f_n(x))$ and suppose $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{(n+1)x+1}$.  Prove that $f_{n+1}(x) = \frac{x}{(n+2)x+1}$.  It's a matter of plugging the hypothesis for $f_n(x)$ into the definition of $f_{n+1}(x)$ and simplifying.

Comment: The main problem with this problem is that your $f_0$ should be called $f_1$ to begin with. In this way $f_0$ is the identity, and $f_{m+n}=f^{\circ m}\circ f^{\circ n}$, etcetera.